# XML format for special characters

Tags: c#, xml

1. What are the special characters that will break an XML?

For example, the following xml works if there is no special characters in the value. But fails when I have & sign. I tried to wrap the value with CDATA syntax (`<![CDATA[CITY & COUNTY]]>`) but getting "Unexpected end of file while parsing CDATA has occurred. Line 44, position 122"

```
<Method ID="5">         
    <Field Type="Text" Name="Company" DisplayName="Company Name" FromBaseType="TRUE" >
        <Default>Rob & Schnider Company</Default>
    </Field> 
</Method>
```

Additional Info (if needed): I am using SharePoint 2010 and it's web services to set default values for certain columns in a document library.

Comment: What are you using to create this XML? String manipulation? Use one of the XML APIs instead. They know how to do this properly.

Comment: I am using Build String action in workflow to create the xml dynamically. Not sure how to go by using XML API in sharepoint workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, since I am using Nintex for workflow there is function which takes care of the special characters. All you do is wrap the value with the the function.

```
fn-XmlEncode
```

Encodes a string to make it safe for view­ing in html.

Exam­ple

```
fn-XmlEncode({WorkflowVariable:Text})
```

Comment: That's one way to do it, but I'd still suggest you find a way to build XML using an XML API like LINQ to XML or XmlDocument. The whole idea of those APIs is that they understand all the rules of XML.

Answer (score 1):

There aren't very many.  there are like 5 characters that you have to escape in your xml.

```
&   &amp;   Ampersand sign
'   &apos;  Single quote
"   &quot;  Double quote
>   &gt;    Greater than
<   &lt;    Less than
```

just change your `&` to a `&amp;`, and it should work.

if you're parsing this with a c# XML library, it should know what to do with the escape sequences.

http://www.rtslink.com/introductionxmlsoap.html